# How do I loop through an array in a template?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I am using [Angular's schematics](https://angular.io/guide/schematics) in a project.

I have an array of numbers: `const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

And I want to print them out in an HTML template. I am passing the array in the following way:

```
export function schematics(_options: Schema): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    const sourceTemplate = url('./files');
    const sourceParametrizedTemplate = apply(sourceTemplate, [
      template({
        ..._options,
        ...strings,
        numbers
      })
    ]);

    return mergeWith(sourceParametrizedTemplate)(tree, _context);
  };
}
```

I was thinking about doing something like this:

index.html

```
<h1>Numbers</h1>

  <%= for(let n in numbers) { =>

  <p><%= n %></p>

  <%= } %>
```

But I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token for`.

Does anyone know what is the correct way of achieving it? I was not able to find it in the documentation.

Thank you!

Comment: That looks like classic asp or maybe asp.net template code. What does that have to do with angular?

Comment: I am using Angular's Schematics. I am going to make it clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found it! I had to use `<%` instead of `<%=` in the blocks with logic.

`<%=` should only be used for blocks that you want to display.

Final version:

```
<h1>Numbers</h1>

  <% for(let n in numbers) { =>

  <p><%= n %></p>

  <% } %>
```

By the way, the result I was looking for I got it using `for ... of ...` instead of `for ... in ...`, but they both work.